# Kubuntu inbuilt webcam problem

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, webcam

I have an issue with my Kubuntu 20.04 OS. The OS doesn't recognize my inbuilt webcam and sometimes it does,earlier it didn't recognize the webcam but now sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. When I attend my zoom calls, sometimes it shows my HP-Webcam and sometimes it doesn't. I have tried cheese and all the shortcut buttons like Fn+F10 and F6 but it doesn't help.

I am using a HP-Notebook -430.

Please help.

Comment: The best thing you could do at this point would be to identify what's different between when it works and when it doesn't.  Start by process of elimination.

Comment: @Nmath I am unable to find any difference except that it suddenly identifies the webcam.